# Convert JSON to XML format through Azure Logic app

Tags: xml-parsing, azure-logic-apps

Scenario 1 - I have some XML files stored in FTP.Those files are being fetched by FTP connector in Azure logic app. Then I am reading those files by parsing it into JSON & storing those objects in String variables for my operation. Then after my processing I want to convert that json back to XML for the output.

Scenario 2 - I am merging multiple XMl files(all are of same structure) into an single one. after merging I can get the output in JSON format but then I want to convert the same into XML format.

So please suggest how can I convert JSON to XML through Logic App & Azure function only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'xml' function. 
[screenshot of xml function example in Logic App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DnZv.jpg)

Make sure that your JSON input is structured suitably for conversion to XML, for example you should only have a single element at the top level, which will form your XML root element.